# How to restrict combination of special characters in asp.net textbox?

Tags: asp.net, regex

This is my code for the asp:textbox-

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="90" 
     CausesValidation="true" SkinID="Skn_inputValue"></asp:TextBox>
```

can I write a regular expression or a javascript code for restricting combination of special characters ie. when I am entering `<,/` or `=` it should be entered as correct input but when I enter any combination of them then it should restict and throw a message.How can I do it?

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="90" CausesValidation="true" SkinID="Skn_inputValue"></asp:TextBox>

This is my code for asp:textbox

Comment: add you comment regarding  TextBox in the question. Also see the answers and see if they work

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Regex much, but if you want to avoid special characters but just digits and alphabets, you can use javascript function like below. Following function won't throw error message but won't allow entry of any special character too, just alphabets and digits.

```
    function isSpecialKey(evt)
     {
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
        if ((charCode>=65 && charCode <=91) || (charCode>=97 && charCode <=123) || (charCode >= 48 || charCode <= 57))
              return true;

        return false;
     }
```

and in your asp textboxt code, call this function on `onkeypress` like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" MaxLength="90" CausesValidation="true" SkinID="Skn_inputValue" onkeypress="return isSpecialKey(event)"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you want to allow any other special character like space, just add the condition for it in the function with the ascii code of it

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps:

```
var specials=/[*|\":<>[\]{}`\\()';@&$]/;

var input=document.getElementById('input_id').value

if (specials.test(input)) { 
  alert("Error");
}
```

Refer this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uofvkz06/1/)